# Is there a maximum thermal conductivity?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

Just like there is a maximum speed and, perhaps, a maximum temperature ("absolute hot"), is there an upper bound on thermal conductivity?

Comment: Thermal conductivity is a material-dependent property. So I think there is nothing with the SR, unless you talk about the different temperature in different frames of references.

Comment: @Jack Yes, of course it's material dependent. I'm wondering if there is an upper limit on the thermal conductivity of any arrangement of matter. Very probably the highest thermal conductivity would not be a single material but a composite like CPU heat pipes which use phase change to dramatically increase conductivity over that of their base materials. I don't expect any connection to SR, not sure where you got that. (Did I mistag?)

Comment: In thoery i don't know, in practice i believe it's graphene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5dwdZCKBZM it's weird material, you can spray it onto silkworm leaves(mulberry tree) and it makes stronger silk than without it.

Comment: Thermal properties seem similar and often related to electrical, copper and alu and gold have some of the highest... actually diamond is much higher than any metal. To find the answer it's best to read the atomic and structural basis of thermal conductivity.

Comment: @comprehensible Yes, I was wondering if anyone has done so and has pointers as to what types of effects are limiting, and if they have any pointers as far as what to read.

Comment: perhaps read about free electrons in conductive metals... delocalized electrons action electrical and thermal conductivity, with exceptions i.e. diamond which has free electrons that are bound within limitid spaces of the matrix. https://phys.org/news/2014-05-physicists-unlimited-graphene.html